# Anchor event listener not recieving few transactions

Tags: anchor

I'm using `@coral-xyz/anchor` TypeScript SDK to listen to certain events emitted by my program. The worker (which contains multiple event listener for various events) have been receiving duplicate transactions i.e the event listener registered for a certain event is receiving the same transaction signature (which emitted the registered event) twice (or sometimes more than twice). I've used the following way-around to filter out the duplicate signatures.

```
const handledSignatures = new Set<string>();
const maxHandledSignatures = 100;

program.addEventListener("eventName", (event, slot, signature) => {
    if (signature === '1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111') return;
    if (handledSignatures.has(signature)) return;
    handledSignatures.add(signature)
    if (handledSignatures.size > maxHandledSignaturesLen) {
      handledSignatures.delete(handledSignatures.values().next().value)
    }

    handledSignatures.add(signature);

   // logic goes here

})
```

Recently I've been noticing that the  registered event listener doesn't receive few of the transactions which have emitted that registered event. It's pretty random and doesn't happen too often but it's pretty important for me that the event listener is able to catch every single transaction which have emitted the event.

Here are 5 transactions which have emitted `Disbursed` event, out of these 5 transactions the worker was only able to catch 4 of them and didn't catch the [3Xayp...](https://explorer.solana.com/tx/3Xayp6zo5fouup15V5WsuRLxpvHZKuuJiXdRPj46twz6jEHeECRdkG9YzpdtfyjsMEFe4xGLgGqmUGHPSvAeD78E?cluster=devnet) transaction. I've confirmed it by checking the logs of the worker. The worker logs every single filtered transaction signature which it has received.

- [53dGtXcSFb81EsSajao8akktzoihkt8PZDcimik76uHmGaGVFVTmQ8uW7XD4QKXnrYVCJZQsshC8y8JJ6tvvqfss](https://explorer.solana.com/tx/53dGtXcSFb81EsSajao8akktzoihkt8PZDcimik76uHmGaGVFVTmQ8uW7XD4QKXnrYVCJZQsshC8y8JJ6tvvqfss?cluster=devnet)
- [3Xayp6zo5fouup15V5WsuRLxpvHZKuuJiXdRPj46twz6jEHeECRdkG9YzpdtfyjsMEFe4xGLgGqmUGHPSvAeD78E](https://explorer.solana.com/tx/3Xayp6zo5fouup15V5WsuRLxpvHZKuuJiXdRPj46twz6jEHeECRdkG9YzpdtfyjsMEFe4xGLgGqmUGHPSvAeD78E?cluster=devnet)
- [5E8YGsCRWL2gQF3pSMtvrJNXfGKbx9WMG39JQ63szZq4dWG5aNwZeNYkNDkL5ug4sBf9sQ9dwbH2vTL5YxbuUy6D](https://explorer.solana.com/tx/5E8YGsCRWL2gQF3pSMtvrJNXfGKbx9WMG39JQ63szZq4dWG5aNwZeNYkNDkL5ug4sBf9sQ9dwbH2vTL5YxbuUy6D?cluster=devnet)
- [jkZ4vdETY8KffPAqUcg4a4qyRkdJRpjhFwBmJtixxUR8Z2V9pFcVdWNfscYGPh2V5QDFab1C1mfvkj1Q46uPUYb](https://explorer.solana.com/tx/jkZ4vdETY8KffPAqUcg4a4qyRkdJRpjhFwBmJtixxUR8Z2V9pFcVdWNfscYGPh2V5QDFab1C1mfvkj1Q46uPUYb?cluster=devnet)
- [2nQXvzLFrCcMBw99wc6tkq7myZRrYH48pCMzuzHaSL7yJNyQKGti4WLSq6i9fXgcnxJmRcb4R5H9Rwp8u8LF35ah](https://explorer.solana.com/tx/2nQXvzLFrCcMBw99wc6tkq7myZRrYH48pCMzuzHaSL7yJNyQKGti4WLSq6i9fXgcnxJmRcb4R5H9Rwp8u8LF35ah?cluster=devnet)